# How to allow characters and whitspaces in PHP with UTF-8 support?

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I want to search/allow characters and whitespaces.
This works with ANSI/LATIN-1 characters:

```
$pattern = '#<a [\W\w]* href="1"#i';
```

I tried this, but obviously it does not work:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
$pattern = '/<a[\pLN\W]* href="1"/ui';
```

Comment: And the *real* answer is: use an HTML parser!? :)

Comment: \w is the opposite of \W thus [\w\W] match all characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead

```
$pattern = '~<a [\pL\s]*\bhref="1"~ui';



<a  #begin with a tag + a space
[\pL\s]*  # zero or more unicode letters or blank characters (space newline tab)
\bhref="1" # href="1" not preceded by a letter or a number

ui # modifier u for unicode string, i case insensitive
```

Comment: Could you explain what the expression does?